# Add Datatime and Time together and convert it in text

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, time

I need to add my work times together and after 10+ hours I have no idea how I should do this. 
The tables look like this:

```
adrID    wrk_Start                      wrk_End                         wrk_Pause
10       01-04-2020 10:00:00            01-04-2020 18:00:00             00:00:00
10       03-04-2020 10:00:00            03-04-2020 17:30:00             00:30:00
10       06-04-2020 12:00:00            06-04-2020 14:00:00             00:00:00
10       12-04-2020 09:00:00            12-04-2020 16:50:00             00:30:00
```

The result should be: 23:30 , mine is 5:00:27

The code is working only if I use little intervals like 10.04.2020 - 12.04.2020 and when I use bigger intervals or intervals that are in the future (today we have 17.04 and I use for ex. 10.04 - 20.04) is not working.

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '01-04-2020 10:00:00';
DECLARE @ToDate DATETIME = '20-04-2020 17:00:00';
DECLARE @user INT = 10;
select convert(varchar, DATEADD(ss, sum(isnull(datediff(second, wrk_Start, wrk_End), 0)), 0), 108)
                from worktime
                where
                wrk_adrID = @wrk_Name and
                wrk_Start >= @wrk_FromDate and
                wrk_End <= @wrk_ToDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normally best to save the dates and time in mysql format, else it gets to much more code:

Your text has to be converted to dates with again get to seconds and finally back to a readable time.

First  comes the mysql version, which had tagged false, and lower you find aSQL SERVER version, which is sowhat more complicated

```
SELECT
     SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,STR_TO_DATE(`wrk_Start`,'%d-%m-%Y %k:%i:%s')
     ,STR_TO_DATE(`wrk_End`,'%d-%m-%Y %k:%i:%s')) 
    - TIME_TO_SEC(`wrk_Pause`)))
FROM
    worktime;
```

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE worktime (
  `wrk_Start` VARCHAR(19),
  `wrk_End` VARCHAR(19),
  `wrk_Pause` Time
);

INSERT INTO worktime
  (`wrk_Start`, `wrk_End`, `wrk_Pause`)
VALUES
  ('01-04-2020 10:00:00', '01-04-2020 18:00:00', '00:00:00'),
  ('03-04-2020 10:00:00', '03-04-2020 17:30:00', '00:30:00'),
  ('06-04-2020 12:00:00', '06-04-2020 14:00:00', '00:00:00'),
  ('12-04-2020 09:00:00', '12-04-2020 16:50:00', '00:30:00');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
     SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,STR_TO_DATE(`wrk_Start`,'%d-%m-%Y %k:%i:%s')
     ,STR_TO_DATE(`wrk_End`,'%d-%m-%Y %k:%i:%s')) 
    - TIME_TO_SEC(`wrk_Pause`)))
FROM
    worktime;

| SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,STR_TO_DATE(`wrk_Start`,'%d-%m-%Y %k:%i:%s')
     ,STR_TO_DATE(`wrk_End`,'%d-%m-%Y %k:%i:%s')) 
    - TIME_TO_SEC(`wrk_Pause`))) |
| --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 24:20:00                                                                                                                                                              |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

**SQL SERVER**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE worktime (
>   wrk_Start nvarchar(19),
>   wrk_End nvarchar(19),
>   wrk_Pause nvarchar(8)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO worktime
>   (wrk_Start, wrk_End, wrk_Pause)
> VALUES
>   ('01-04-2020 10:00:00', '01-04-2020 18:00:00', '00:00:00'),
>   ('03-04-2020 10:00:00', '03-04-2020 17:30:00', '00:30:00'),
>   ('06-04-2020 12:00:00', '06-04-2020 14:00:00', '00:00:00'),
>   ('12-04-2020 09:00:00', '12-04-2020 16:50:00', '00:30:00');
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 4 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> (SUM(DATEDIFF(second,CONVERT(DATETIME,[wrk_Start]),
> CONVERT(DATETIME,[wrk_End])) -
> DATEDIFF(second,'00:00:00',[wrk_Pause]))) wrktime
> FROM
> worktime;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | wrktime |
> | ------: |
> |   87600 |
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @seconds AS int = 896434;
> SELECT CONVERT(varchar, (SUM(DATEDIFF(second,CONVERT(DATETIME,[wrk_Start]),
> CONVERT(DATETIME,[wrk_End])) -
> DATEDIFF(second,'00:00:00',[wrk_Pause]))) / 86400 ) + ':' + -- Days
> CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, ( (SUM(DATEDIFF(second,CONVERT(DATETIME,[wrk_Start]),
> CONVERT(DATETIME,[wrk_End])) -
> DATEDIFF(second,'00:00:00',[wrk_Pause]))) % 86400 ) * 1000, 0), 108)
> as "orktime"
> FROM
> worktime;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | orktime    |
> | :--------- |
> | 1:00:20:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=deaf03f167e7f89fdf2441cae4a463bc)*

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I'll try this tommorow at 10 am. What if there is more data than just that what I gave you ? I mean there is gonna be at least +3 data per day.

Comment: You have to convert the dates and treat it like every other datime oyu encounter in the free world. Always remeber mysql stored the dates in anotgher way if you want to use date functions like year and so on. Dateformat is 2020-04-17 07:59:38

Comment: this is only for mysqk, that doesn't work on sql server

Answer (score 1):

First, don't try to convert the value back to a time -- SQL Server does not allow times that exceed 24 hours.

I would go for decimal hours.  That would be:

```
select adrid,
       (sum(datediff(second, wrk_start, wrk_end))-
        sum(datediff(second, '00:00:00', wrk_pause))
       )  / (60.0 * 60) as decimal_hours
from worktime
group by adrid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f75c46856cfcd2eb9970e09d9e9a9c1) is a db<>fiddle.